# How to Solve this Particular Euler Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to solve an Euler ODE:

Here's my work so far:

> I'm asked to solve the following Euler DE using the method of variation of parameters:
>   $$x^2y''-y=(x^2+1)\sin{x}$$
>   I already determined the homogeneous solution which resulted in:
>   $$y_h=c_1 x^{\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}+c_2 x^{\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}$$
>   I'm having trouble finding the particular solution though...
>   $$y_p=u_1 y_1+u_2 y_2$$
>   $$u_1=-\int \frac{R(x)\cdot y_2}{W}~dx \qquad \qquad  W=\text{wronskian}=-\sqrt{5}$$
>   $$u_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int (x^2+1)\sin{x}\cdot x^{\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}~dx$$
>   But this integral is too complicated for me to solve. I computed it and found that it gives a gamma function and a really long answer. Is there anything I missed that could simplify this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y''-y=(x^2+1)\sin(x)$$
Since $\quad \left(\sin(x)\right)''=-\sin(x)\quad$ obviously $\quad y=-\sin(x)\quad$ is a particular solution. Hence :
$$y(x)=c_1 x^{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}+c_2 x^{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}-\sin(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the mistake you made: You forgot to divide the differential equation by $x^2$ to obtain:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{(x^2+1)\cdot \sin{x}}{x^2}$$
Therefore, your $R(x)\neq (x^2+1)\sin{x}$, but in fact:
$$R(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)\cdot \sin{x}}{x^2}$$

---

Hence, you should have:
$$u_1=-\int \frac{R(x)\cdot y_2}{W}~dx=\int \frac{\left(\frac{(x^2+1)\cdot \sin{x}}{x^2}\right)\cdot x^{\frac{-\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}}{\sqrt{5}}~dx$$
$$u_1=\int \frac{(x^2+1)\cdot \sin{x}\cdot x^{\frac{-\sqrt{5}-3}{2}}}{\sqrt{5}}~dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \int (x^2+1)\cdot \sin{x}\cdot x^{\frac{-\sqrt{5}-3}{2}}~dx$$
Evaluating **this** integral should **not** give gamma functions (Should be in terms of elementary functions). As you correctly mentioned, the solution to the indefinite integral you incorrectly derived contains the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Putting everything together (Don't forget to evaluate $u_2$) and cancelling everything should eventually gives a nice particular solution:
$$y_p=-\sin(x)$$